# How get in Azure access_token from Azure Function app with id_token?

Tags: c#, azure, access-token, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to get authorisation and an access&refresh token when a user accesses an Anonymous Function App.

I have followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ravindraa/secure-azure-functions-using-azure-ad-b2c-986e4ad07c6c) to use a B2C tenant authorisation of the Function App.

I can get the id_token with this in the function app.  To get the token I paste in browser the address of the Function app:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            string code = null;
            foreach (var h in req.Headers)
            {
                if(h.Key.Equals("X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN"))
                    code += (h.Value);//authorisation id_token to get access_token
            }
```

I have tried several tutorials to get access/refresh token and this [one](https://medium.com/@atishubh.vaishnaw/creating-an-azure-function-that-generates-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-rest-api-aebf8cd57ecf) I could follow/understand: I see in Fiddler I get id_token at https://tenantName.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback; but the next line https://functionAppName.azurewebsites.net/api/functionName GET request, the response is Server Error, 404 - File or directory not found.":

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            string code = null;
            foreach (var h in req.Headers)
            {
                if(h.Key.Equals("X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN"))
                    code += (h.Value);
            }
var content = new StringContent(
                "grant_type=refresh_token" +
                "&client_id=" + B2CApplication-ApiID+
                "&redirect_uri="+"https://functionapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback"+
                "&client_secret="+"XXX"+
                "&code" + code +
                "&scope=user.read"+
                "&resource="+"https://graph.microsoft.com",//also tried https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    BaseURL="https://tenantName.b2clogin.com/tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(BaseURL, content);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
    var access_token = json.access_token;
    var refresh_token = json.refresh_token;
    string token_value = access_token.value; 
    string refresh_value = refresh_token.value;
    return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Complete " ,{token_value});
```

This is the set up:

```
    Azure AD B2C Tenant
    Domain Name: tenantName.onmicrosoft.com
    Applications: B2CApplication-Api
        WebApp/API : Yes
        Allow Implicit Flow : Yes
        Reply Url : https://functionapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
        App ID : https://tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/B2CApplication-Api
        Add URI (optional): identityauth
        Include Native client: No
        Secret key: XXX
        Reply URL: https://tenantName.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
        API Access to Microsoft Graph: Read User Profile with granted admin consent
        Published Scope read: https://tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/identityauth/read
        Published Scope user_impersonation: https://tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/identityauth/user_impersonation
    User Flows
        SignupSignIn, Password reset, profile editing
        Application : B2CApplication-Api
        Reply Url : https://tenantName.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback


    Azure Function: Anonymous
    App Service Authentication : On
    Action to take when not authenticated : Login with Azure AD
    Authentication provider:Azure AAD
        Management Mode : Advanced
        client id : B2C-Application-ApplicationID
        issuer url : https://tenantName.b2clogin.com/tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_signinsignoutpolicy
        Allowed Token Audiences: B2C-Application-Application_ID
```

Comment: You only show the refresh_token grant call above; what happens when you try the authorization_code grant?

Comment: Hi @sellotape I get the same response Server Error, 404 - File or directory not found. But I understand I have the id_token (authorization_code) and the request i send is for both acces_code and refresh https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code

Comment: quite confusing, which is access_token? the diagram in this link shows the first code the user gets is authorization_code to later get access_code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code but other documents point to grant_type=authorization_code to get the access_token  (section 3) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Comment: The ID token is generally of no value for authorising requests; only an access token will do. You need to get that *and* a refresh token (if necessary) to refresh an existing access token. Are you sure your URLs are all correct; e.g. substituting your actual tenant name/ID into them?

Comment: but for this query construction (I couldn't get any other to work) I need the id_token to request the access_token. Yes I do think the urls are right, i was unsure about https://graph.microsoft.com but i've tried what is used in this example (ending with /.default) and still get same error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Comment: should i be adding resouce in content? Here I don't see it added to request the access_token https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Comment: found a discrepancy in an address between my code and what I had pasted in post, now updated, apologies. I also find weird I don't need to pass the tenantID but I can't find a parallel example with this setup to figure out what i'm doing wrong

Comment: First, I would remove the confusion around refresh tokens and just try to get an access token at this point, using the authorization_code grant.  Then, is your b2c tenant actually called "tenantName", or are you just substituting that to not display the real one?  You could (initially, anyway) try use "login.microsoftonline.com" instead of "tenantName.b2clogin.com" (it's [valid until Dec 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin)) and see whether that gets you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Azure AD B2C access tokens can only be used to access your own protected resources.**

We cannot use the Azure AD B2C issued access token to call Microsoft Graph API. You must have the user call your API, and your API needs to use client_credentials to obtain a token for Graph API.

And, `https://graph.microsoft.com` is for resource(v1.0) and `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` is for scope(v2.0). You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#scopes-not-resources) for the details.

Reference:

[B2C calling a Web API you own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=applications)

[AAD calling MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-netcore-daemon)